# How to create a java interface to compile c# code, and then generate dll's?

Tags: c#, java, dll, interface

I would like to start coding  a java interface but I want that The internal funcionality is to generate dll's from c# codes, I have several projects which several c# classes...

Basically the idea is to make a setup, so there would be a .zip or .rar wich will contain all  c# projects and a java exe which, when executed, will compile c# projects and then place the dll's in a specific directory,

Do you know any example of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mentioned Portability ,than i think you need to run that java App. also at Linux and Mac ,so instead of MSBuild which work's only at Windows ,you can try http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler Mono Compiler which is Cross Platform .

Answer (score 3):

You can use MSBuild to build .NET projects from the command line, which I think would be easy for you to call from Java code (though I don't understand why you are trying to use a Java program to trigger a compilation).

Read about MSBuild here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I would like Java because of portable issues, and want to trigger a compilation because the main project is in c#, in fact I would like to make a .bat file but having the advantages of a java swing interface

Comment: ah ok. then I guess MSBuild (or a similar tool) would do. Hope its easy to call a command line tool in swing. Here's a HUGE list of build automation tools (not all are for .NET): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software

Comment: @Guganeshan.T he say's he need Java because of Portability ,but MSBuild it's not so Portable ,maybe he need to check Mono and it's tool's.

Comment: That's why I was confused about his java executable choice. If that is the case, then you are right, Mono is the way to go :)